# Mass beta testing of application

Tags: iphone, xcode, apple-push-notifications, beta

I have a beta application that I want to show to 100+ people and I can't figure out how I can do it without the app store. The thing is with the app store it's a beta. In the app it has pages that do nothing because I want to show the people what I'm working on next.

What adds to the problem is that the application is Push notification enabled.

I'm guessing if I sent the files of the code that the certificates would change because they would have to make a new provisioning cert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://testflightapp.com is a great tool for distributing beta tests.  As for the 100+, it will only support 100 a year as per Apple's ad-hoc constraint, up to 200 devices.  To test with more people, you'll need to sign the app again with another developer account and distribute to a second list.  Other options include enterprise deployment or having some testers build and deploy for themselves, signing with their own developer account.